# Why can't my phone acces my router on WDS mode?

Tags: wireless-bridge, wds

I have a TP-Link AC1200 router which is on WDS mode with another modem (Sitecom) because I can't run a cable from my modem to my router upstairs. Everything is fine and working good except my phone.
My phone keeps telling: obtaining IP address
I tried this with a Galaxy S5 and an IPhone 5s, without success...

Any ideas?

Comment: WDS _bridge_ mode, or WDS _repeater_ mode?

Comment: WDS bridge mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I performed a hard reset and bought a second tp-link router. With this configuration I managed to get everything working again.